# $lookup when localField is nested

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

**MongoDB version 3.4.10** (Application is using Meteor framework)

**Objective**: Aggregate documents that are referenced by _id into the containing document as required at runtime.

I have `Materials`, `Models`, and `Catalog` collections with the following documents:

**Materials**

```
 { "_id" : "cf4KgXw7ZK6ukdzR7", "name" : "parquet_wood_mahogany" }
```

**Models**

```
{
  "_id" : "Mwp5eYYZ4GZzvZuoK",
  "name" : "top_square_chamfered",
  "type" : "top"
}
{
  "_id" : "CqhS2m2RcLZ2Bm4eb",
  "name" : "skirt_square",
  "type" : "skirt"
}
{
  "_id" : "dYP22ajALnWBwpBj2",
  "name" : "leg_square",
  "type" : "leg"
}
```

**Catalog**

```
{
  "_id" : "EcRGzPAq79giYKrbY",
  ...,
  "specs" : {
    ...,
    "models" : [
      {
        "mesh" : "Mwp5eYYZ4GZzvZuoK",
        "material" : "cf4KgXw7ZK6ukdzR7"
      },
      {
        "mesh" : "CqhS2m2RcLZ2Bm4eb",
        "material" : "cf4KgXw7ZK6ukdzR7"
      },
      {
        "mesh" : "dYP22ajALnWBwpBj2",
        "material" : "cf4KgXw7ZK6ukdzR7"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Desired** returned document format after aggregation:

```
{
  "_id" : "EcRGzPAq79giYKrbY",
  ...,
  "specs" : {
    "dimensions" : {
      ...,
    },
    "models" : [
      {
        "mesh" : {
          "_id" : "Mwp5eYYZ4GZzvZuoK",
          "name" : "top_square_chamfered",
          "type" : "top"
        },
        "material" : {
          "_id" : "cf4KgXw7ZK6ukdzR7",
          "name" : "parquet_wood_mahogany"
        }
      },
      {
        "mesh" : {
          "_id" : "CqhS2m2RcLZ2Bm4eb",
          "name" : "skirt_square",
          "type" : "skirt"
        },
        "material" : {
          "_id" : "cf4KgXw7ZK6ukdzR7",
          "name" : "parquet_wood_mahogany"
        }
      },
      {
        "mesh" : {
          "_id" : "dYP22ajALnWBwpBj2",
          "name" : "leg_square",
          "type" : "leg"
        },
        "material" : {
          "_id" : "cf4KgXw7ZK6ukdzR7",
          "name" : "parquet_wood_mahogany"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I haven't included any of my query code because it is so far off the mark as to just be noise.  I've been trying to use `aggregate`, with `$lookup` combinations, but I'm not getting anywhere close to what I'm after. The MongoDB v3.6 `pipeline` syntax would make this much easier... but I'm at a complete loss in v3.4.

I would like to avoid using multiple database requests to combine this information if at all possible. Any assistance of advice would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Working solution -

```
db.catalog.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": 'models',
    "localField": "specs.models.mesh",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "models.mesh"
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": 'materials',
    "localField": "specs.models.material",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "models.material"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$models.mesh" },
  { "$unwind": "$models.material" },
  { "$group":{
    "_id": "$_id",
    "title": { "$first": "$title" },
    "desc": { "$first": "$desc" },
    "thumbnail": { "$first": "$thumbnail" },
    "createdBy": { "$first": "$createdBy" },
    "createdAt": { "$first": "$createdAt" },
    "specs": { "$first": "$specs" },
    "models": { "$push": "$models" }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "title": "$title",
    "desc": "$desc",
    "thumbnail": "$thumbnail",
    "createdBy": "$createdBy",
    "createdAt": "$createdAt",
    "specs.dimensions": "$specs.dimensions",
    "specs.models": "$models",
  }}
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

```
db.catalog.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": 'models',
    "localField": "specs.models.mesh",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "models.mesh"
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": 'materials',
    "localField": "specs.models.material",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "models.material"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$models.mesh" },
  { "$unwind": "$models.material" },
  { "$group":{
    "_id": "$_id",
    "title": { "$first": "$title" },
    "desc": { "$first": "$desc" },
    "thumbnail": { "$first": "$thumbnail" },
    "createdBy": { "$first": "$createdBy" },
    "createdAt": { "$first": "$createdAt" },
    "specs": { "$first": "$specs" },
    "models": { "$push": "$models" }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "title": "$title",
    "desc": "$desc",
    "thumbnail": "$thumbnail",
    "createdBy": "$createdBy",
    "createdAt": "$createdAt",
    "specs.dimensions": "$specs.dimensions",
    "specs.models": "$models",
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm trying your query and adjusting it, but I'm not getting any results returned. `Models.collection.name` and `Materials.collection.name` were changed to their names; `models` and `materials` respectively.

Comment: probably your `Models.collection.name`/`Materials.collection.name` would not be correct.... otherwise it should work

Comment: I'm making adjustments and it is coming together. You've pointed me in the right direction. The models.mesh and models.materials need specs. in front of them. The first $unwind is not required. I'll post again here in a moment, almost got it.

Comment: @KyleRichardson got it what I was doing wrong... Please check the updated answer

Comment: That's what I'm trying to get to work at the moment. Though it is throwing an error that 'the specs field must be an accumulator object' I posted an edit with the query I'm using.

Comment: I have a working query. Going to post it in my question. Update your answer and I'll accept it. Wouldn't of gotten here without you! Thank you! P.S. It seems a little over complex :(